# Best way to add a event listener inside a loop and get element's tag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

I have to add a listener to all checkboxes inside a LinearLayout and, every time that a click happens on each element, check the tag value. I did something like this, but I'm not comfortable declaring a String inside a looping. Any best practices tips?

```
    ViewGroup generalContainer = (ViewGroup) contextView;
    ViewGroup optionsContainer = (ViewGroup) generalContainer.getChildAt(0);
    int len = optionsContainer.getChildCount();
    CheckBox currentCheckBox;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        currentCheckBox = (CheckBox) optionsContainer.getChildAt(i);
        final String currentTag = (String) currentCheckBox.getTag().toString();

        currentCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    Log.i("ulog", "is checked " + currentTag);

                } else {
                    Log.i("ulog", "not checked " + currentTag);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If your code works, it may be better to ask http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a more efficient way, you can declare a single `OnClickListener` for all of your `CheckBox` instances. (I assume you are setting unique tags to your checkBoxes while creating them.)

So there is no problem to use tags as string if you guaranteed them to be unique.

```
OnClickListener checkBoxOnClickLister = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox checkBox = ((CheckBox) v);
        String currentTag = (String) checkBox.getTag();

        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            Log.i("ulog", "is checked " + currentTag);

        } else {
            Log.i("ulog", "not checked " + currentTag);
        }
    }
};

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    currentCheckBox = (CheckBox) optionsContainer.getChildAt(i);
    currentCheckBox.setOnClickListener(checkBoxOnClickLister);
}
```